# running a func after getDataInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: swift, parse-platform

All , I run this function in swift to get images in an array (of UImages)

```
func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {
        for object in objects {
            let thumbNail = object["StaffPic"] as PFFile

            thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    println(image)
                    self.logoImages.append(image)
```

is there something I can use to run an function on the main thread after this has been executed ? 
 I have created a test function :

```
func displayImages()
{
    if self.logoImages.isEmpty
    {
        println("Logos are empty")
    }
    else
    {
        println(self.logoImages.count)
    }
}
```

But this is always - Logos are empty, because it runs it before the getDataInBackgroundBlock is completed. Any help would be great.

if i add this :

```
  func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {
        for object in objects {
            let thumbNail = object["StaffPic"] as PFFile

            thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    println(image)
                    self.logoImages.append(image)

                }


            }, progressBlock: {
                (percentDone: Int) -> Void in

        })
```

so I have added progressBlock at the end of the function. It does not recognise progressBlock..

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by

```
  }, progressBlock: {(percentDone: CInt) -> Void in

    })
```

using CInt and not Int

Comment: If you don't mind can you post the full function? I am trying to figure out the same problem.